# Can you tell me the effect of 'comma' on 'the'?

Tags: punctuation

[Oakmont shows no mercy](http://www.pressreader.com/)

> Let the clumsy,the spineless,the alibi artist stand aside.

It can be rewritten as *Let the clumsy,the spineless and alibi artist stand aside*.Am I right if one *the* is omitted when placed *and.*

Also, what does it means by 'alibi artist'?

Another example: *He is the handsome and smart PM of USA.*We do not put *the*
with *smart*.

Comment: [*When Pittsburgh industrialist H.C. Fownes built the Oakmont Country Club in **1903**, he declared: "**Let the clumsy, the spineless, the alibi artist, stand aside!**"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+declared+Let+the+clumsy+the+spineless%22) It's a somewhat "dated" declaratory style today, which is why you'll find different versions in later regurgitations.

Comment: What is 'in later regurgitations'?

Comment: [regurgitate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/regurgitate) - *to give back or **repeat,** especially something not fully understood or assimilated.* I mean people tend to adjust the wording slightly to conform to more modern idiomatic phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence

> Let the clumsy, the spineless, the alibi artist stand aside.

refers to

> the clumsy artist
>   the spineless artist
>   the alibi artist

if you changed it to

> Let the clumsy, the spineless and alibi artist stand aside.

it would refer to

> the clumsy artist
>   the spineless and alibi artist

So the two are not equivalent.

An "alibi" is an excuse for not being at the scene of a crime.
So an "alibi" artist could be understood to be someone who is

> an excuse for an artist

the speaker seems to be attacking people who claim to be artists but are not really.